Covering or turning over her food
My dog has recently started covering her food, and once tried to cover mine.  If it is a treat and I put it on a plate, instead of her food bowl she will turn it over.  If I take it and give it to her by hand, she is fine.  I am really hoping she isn’t trying to tell me that I am supposed to hand feed every bite.  She thinks she is the princess, but that would be a whole other level.
Thank you.

DO NOT start feeding her every bit by hand. No dog ever needs that because they are perfectly capable of eating from a bowl or plate or whatever. This is most likely just a habit or odd behavior she has, you don't want to add the habit of hand-feeding her. If the doesn't take the treat or food, it is not that important to her in that very moment. She might enjoying interacting (like playing) with you more than eating the treat. She might come back later an take it then.
